# How to format an SD card as adoptable storage on Android 5?

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, external-sd, storage, adoptable-storage

I have ZTE phone:

> Model z828
>
> Fcc id srq-z828 IC 5200E-Z828
>
> H/W U06A
>
> DATE 03/2017

and have inserted and mounted a 32 GB SD storage chip.  However, cannot seem to get an option to use [adoptable](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) storage.

In settings, storage I see options to unmount or format the SD card -- but no option to [adopt](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info).

**Operating System version number:  5.1.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model ships originally with Android 5.1. Adoptable storage was introduced in [Android 6.0](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable) .

So even if you update to Android 6, is probably that you wont have the option.

Also some manufacturers, dont allow this option, so if the option doesnt appear, or the option to move apps to the sd card doesnt appear, the option is not available.
It happened to me on a Galaxy J5 2015 with Android 5.1 that got the Android 6.0 update, and still doesnt work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Thufir So is my answer helpful?

Comment: I think that I need to update the OS.  Perhaps there's a third party, as I doubt ZTE does updates.  If I can get to Android 6, or similar, it might fix a few problems.  Portable storage being the most important.