# How to free up space to install apps?

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, external-sd, storage, zte

After installing a 32 GB SD card, having trouble installing apps.  Because the OS is 5.x and [not](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200529/48164) upgradable then [adoptable](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200522/48164) storage isn't an option.

How can I install apps when the system reports insufficient free space?  Every app I've downloaded has been moved to SD card, yet, the prompt is to uninstall these apps.  To reiterate, every app which I'm being prompted to uninstall has already been moved to external storage.

Seems a conundrum.

---

After resetting to factory default I then installed [Disk Analysis](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.storage.space.es.diskanalyzer&hl=en) for defrag on the system storage.

Comment: You don't defrag solid state storage... it just wears on the chip which has limited write cycles. Even when apps are "moved" to external storage, only a portion of that data is actually moved. Before an app can be moved, it must be installed on the internal storage first, that is why the OS is telling you that you have insufficient space. A third party tool is normally not necessary, use Settings - Storage to see what is using space and uninstall, delete, or move the files to free up space.

Comment: Also, force stop those system apps which you don't use and uninstall updates for them. They will free up some space

Comment: You can move the app to the sd-card, however the OAT files (the ART compiled code that is actually been executed) will still be placed on the user partition. Therefore deleting unused apps is the the best option.

Comment: If you have root, just disable internal memory and use SDCard as internal memory. It's a bit hacking stuff but simple. I use a 64GB SDCard as internal memory on an older phone with 16GB eMMC.